# How to find a minimum double from a set of numbers. I can get it with this code, but is there a simpler way?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class MinimumNum {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  Double max1, max2, max3, max4, max5, max6, max7, max8, max9, max10;
  double min = 0;

  System.out.println("Enter the first number");
  max1 = in .nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Enter the second number");
  max2 = in .nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Enter the third number");
  max3 = in .nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Enter the fourth number");
  max4 = in .nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Enter the fifth number");
  max5 = in .nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Enter the sixth number");
  max6 = in .nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Enter the seventh number");
  max7 = in .nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Enter the eighth number");
  max8 = in .nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Enter the ninth number");
  max9 = in .nextDouble();
  System.out.println("Enter the tenth number");
  max10 = in .nextDouble();

  if (max1 < max10 && max1 < max9 && max1 < max8 && max1 < max7 && max1 < max6 && max1 < max5 && max1 < max4 && max1 < max3 && max1 < max2) {
   min = max1;
  } else if (max2 < max10 && max2 < max9 && max2 < max8 && max2 < max7 && max2 < max6 && max2 < max5 && max2 < max4 && max2 < max3 && max2 < max1) {
   min = max2;
  } else if (max3 < max10 && max3 < max9 && max3 < max8 && max3 < max7 && max3 < max6 && max3 < max5 && max3 < max4 && max3 < max2 && max3 < max1) {
   min = max3;
  } else if (max4 < max10 && max4 < max9 && max4 < max8 && max4 < max7 && max4 < max6 && max4 < max5 && max4 < max3 && max4 < max2 && max4 < max1) {
   min = max4;
  } else if (max5 < max10 && max5 < max9 && max5 < max8 && max5 < max7 && max5 < max6 && max5 < max4 && max5 < max3 && max5 < max2 && max5 < max1) {
   min = max5;
  } else if (max6 < max10 && max6 < max9 && max6 < max8 && max6 < max7 && max6 < max5 && max6 < max4 && max6 < max3 && max6 < max2 && max6 < max1) {
   min = max6;
  } else if (max7 < max10 && max7 < max9 && max7 < max8 && max7 < max6 && max7 < max5 && max7 < max4 && max7 < max3 && max7 < max2 && max7 < max1) {
   min = max7;
  } else if (max8 < max10 && max8 < max9 && max8 < max7 && max8 < max6 && max8 < max5 && max8 < max4 && max8 < max3 && max8 < max2 && max8 < max1) {
   min = max8;
  } else if (max9 < max10 && max9 < max8 && max9 < max7 && max9 < max6 && max9 < max5 && max9 < max4 && max9 < max3 && max9 < max2 && max9 < max1) {
   min = max9;
  } else if (max10 < max9 && max10 < max8 && max10 < max7 && max10 < max6 && max10 < max5 && max10 < max4 && max10 < max3 && max10 < max2 && max10 < max1) {
   min = max10;
  }


  System.out.println(min);
 }

}
```

Comment: have you heard of arrays?

Answer (score 2):

You have many choices:

- if you don't need all of the numbers since you are interested just in maximum then you can use a loop and keep the higher value at each iteration
- you can store them in an array and then search for max element
- you can use a [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) such as [`TreeSet<Double>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and just take the `first()`/`last()` element

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic example which is limited to 10 inputs and gives you a minimum value, better method would be to store those inputs into an array and then sort it to get min or max value (). Look at `Arrays.sort();`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int max=10;
        int count =0;

        double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        while(count<max){
            double temp = in.nextDouble();
            if(temp<min){
                min = temp;
            }
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println(min);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of, in Java 8+, would be to use a [`DoubleStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html) to get it like

```
double min = DoubleStream.of(max1, max2, max3, max4, max5, max6, max7, 
        max8, max9, max10).min().getAsDouble();
```

Alternatively, you could chain a sequence of [`Math.min(double, double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-double-double-) calls or break it into a varargs method like

```
static double getMin(double... vals) {
    double min = vals[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < vals.length; i++) {
        min = Math.min(vals[i], min);
    }
    return min;
}
```

And then call it like

```
double min = getMin(max1, max2, max3, max4, max5, max6, max7, max8, max9, max10);
```